# How to match on at least 2 where conditions?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing five boolean columns.

How can I construct a query that returns rows where at least 2 columns are true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast the boolean types to integer (`0=false`, `1=true`) and check their sum:

```
select *
from my_table
where a::int + b::int + c::int + d::int + e::int >= 2;
```

Comment: That's some efficient coding

Answer (score 2):

The long way:

```
SELECT * from t where c1 and c2 or c1 and c3 or c1 and c4 or c1 and c5
or c2 and c3 or c2 and c4 or c2 and c5 or c3 and c4 or c3 and c5 or c4 and c5;
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer only works assuming all columns are defined `NOT NULL`, which has not been specified. To make it work with `NULL`, too:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE (a IS TRUE)::int
    + (b IS TRUE)::int
    + (c IS TRUE)::int
    + (d IS TRUE)::int
    + (e IS TRUE)::int > 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  COALESCE(a::int, 0)
     + COALESCE(b::int, 0)
     + COALESCE(c::int, 0)
     + COALESCE(d::int, 0)
     + COALESCE(e::int, 0) > 1;
```